# check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to insert into database but it giving me an error (check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near (Long,Lat,name,ReturnAddress, Division)

im using php,mysql. I need to success result,

```
 //Insert new row with user data
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO map " .
        " ( Id, Lat, Long, Name, ReturnAddress, Division ) " .
        " VALUES ('%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s');",
         mysql_real_escape_string($ID),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($name),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($address),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($type));


$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
```

and the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, 36.1419);
      var options = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
                 "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
                 "<option value='normal home' SELECTED>normal home</option>" +
                 "<option value='villa'>villa</option>" +
                 "</select> </td></tr>" +
                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
    }

    function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();

      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();

        }
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          alert(request.responseText);
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
           window.open('index.php','_self',false);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send();
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the database :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map` (
  `Id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Lat` float NOT NULL,
  `Long` float NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ReturnAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Division` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long` is a reserved word enclose it in backticks

```
`long`
```